# Bug in DateTime handling of Cosmos DB DocumentClient

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This question relates to `DocumentClient` from `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v2.11.2`. (Update: the bug also exists in `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`.)

There seems to be a bug in the LINQ Provider for Cosmos DB when the query contains `DateTime` values with trailing zeros. Consider the following piece of code:

```
string dateTimeWithTrailingZero = "2000-01-01T00:00:00.1234560Z"; // trailing zero will be truncated by LINQ provider :-(
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeWithTrailingZero, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

IQueryable<Dictionary<string, object>> query =
    client.CreateDocumentQuery<Dictionary<string, object>>(collectionUri)
        .Where(x => (DateTime) x["datetime"] <= datetime);
```

The result of `query` **includes** documents where the property `datetime` is e.g. `"2000-01-01T00:00:00.1234567Z"` (even though it **should not**).

The result of `query` does **not include** documents where `datetime` is `"2000-01-01T00:00:00.1234560Z"` (even though it **should**).

Is there any way I can use `DocumentClient` and LINQ to query `DateTime` properties correctly? (I know that using raw SQL works - for various reasons I **must** use LINQ/`IQueryable`.)

Comment: The fix is to upgrade to a version of the library that isn't ancient: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/

Comment: @Ian Kemp: Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v2.11.2 is from July 14, 2020, not exactly ancient. But it may be worth moving to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos - are you sure the bug has been fixed there? Much of the LINQ provider code seems identical...

Comment: @Ian Kemp: I just checked, and the bug also exists in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.

Comment: Then I suggest you file an issue on their GitHub explaining this, and I'm sure they'll try to help you figure out a workaround as well as put in a fix for it.

Comment: The issue has been reported here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to use a custom `JsonConverter`. Unfortunately, with `DocumentClient`, setting the `JsonConverter` in the constructor of `DocumentClient` does **not** work! The converter is only picked up properly when it is specified in the global (static) JSON.NET default settings (`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`).

For the newer `CosmosClient`, it is necessary and sufficient to set a custom `CosmosSerializer` in the constructor. To write a custom `CosmosSerializer` which lets you specify a custom `JsonSerializerSettings`, you can decompile the internal class `CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer` and use that as the basis.

The custom `JsonConverter` looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="JsonConverter" /> for Cosmos DB needed as long as the DateTime handling
/// problem has not been fixed. 
/// </summary>
public class CosmosDbDateTimeJsonConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CosmosDbDateTimeJsonConverter()
    {
        this.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK";
    }

    #region Overrides of JsonConverter

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override bool CanRead => false;

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is removing/truncating the last '0' before 'Z' and hence the final query is working like:

```
query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root[\"datetime\"] < \"2000-01-01T00:00:00.123456Z\") "
```

Thats why this is giving unwanted results. This is strange behavior and I don't think much can be done there.

You make the string as `string dateTimeWithTrailingZero = "2000-01-01T00:00:00.1234561Z"` and this will work fine.

Another way of doing the same is:

```
string dateTimeWithTrailingZero = "2000-01-01T00:00:00.1234560Z";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeWithTrailingZero, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

var result= client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demoDb", "demoDocCollection"),"select * from c where c.datetime < '" + datetime.ToString("o") + "'").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it was already clear *why* and *when* the bug occurs (hence the suggestive variable name "dateTimeWithTrailingZero". And as the question states, I have to use LINQ, not raw SQL; the reason being that I already have a LINQ IQueryable expression, which at some point has to be extended with a datetime constraint at runtime. And unfortunately, SQL and LINQ cannot be mixed, so in particular, you can't add an SQL WHERE-clause to an IQueryable.